# Is it possible to add values in an existing cookie in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, cookies

I want to add three extra values as in firstname, lastname and title in existing cookie before loading a webview URL, so that user doesnt have to login again in the webview.. Is it possible to add extra values in an existing cookie in Objective C ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add your own cookie with `NSHTTPCookie` and `NSHTTPCookieStorage`

1) Create dictionary to set properties of cookie like (below are few properties of cookie):

```
   NSMutableDictionary *dictCookieID = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dictCookieID setObject:value forKey:NSHTTPCookieName];
    [dictCookieID setObject:value forKey:NSHTTPCookieValue];
    [dictCookieID setObject:value forKey:NSHTTPCookieDomain];
    [dictCookieID setObject:value forKey:NSHTTPCookiePath];
    [dictCookieID setObject:value forKey:NSHTTPCookieVersion];
```

2) Create a object of  `NSHTTPCookie`

```
    NSHTTPCookie *cookieID = [NSHTTPCookie dictCookieID];
```

3) Store cookie :

```
   NSArray *cookies = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: cookieID,nil]; // You can add multiple cookies in this array
   [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]  cookieID];
   [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];
```

4) Load url to webview:

```
    NSString* url = URL_NAME;
    NSURL* nsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:nsUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];

    NSDictionary * headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:cookies];
    [(NSMutableURLRequest *)request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];

    [webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Note that while this satisfied the poster, it doesn't actually answer the question, which I assume to be how do you modify an existing NSHTTPCookie. I can only assume the question has been edited and the title remained. It might be worth editing it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using `NSURLSession` you can set cookies in [`NSHTTPCookieStorage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/index.html). However, a cookie is simply a header field you can set.

Comment: Did you follow my link?

Comment: Yes, should I use setCookies:forURL:mainDocumentURL ?